# Customizing the WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 management console's interface

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I tried to follow the steps given in the below WSO2 documentation link to customize the APIM management console's interface but the changes don't reflect after restarting the carbon server. Need suggestions on this.

Documentation link: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/advance-configurations/customizing-the-management-console/#!

Steps followed as per documentation:

1. Copied the org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.0.jar from <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/plugins/ to a separate location.
2. Created a MMP with name org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.0_patch and added new css file and image file under the MMP. Copied the template.jsp from the org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.0.jar and placed it under this MMP project. Within this jsp file, reference of the new css file was added.
3. Created one more MMP with name org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.0_fragment and within its pom.xml added a plugin to point to the org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.6.0_patch MMP.
4. Created jars for both the MMPs' using maven and copied them under <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/dropins/.
5. Restarted the WSO2 APIM server but the changes didn't reflect in the management console (https://localhost:9443/carbon) as given in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions given in documentation [1]. The document that you have pointed out has to be updated.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/customizing-the-management-console/#customizing-the-management-console

Comment: Hi Tharika, i tried to change the left logo that appears at top by following the steps in the documentation that you shared above. I placed a new logo image under ../web/styles/images and also made the required change in ../web/styles/css/main.css to point to this new logo.  After the APIM server restart the logo gets modified but i don't see the expected logo that i had placed in the org.wso2.am.styles_3.1.0.jar. I tried with multiple different logos but every time i see the same logo and not the one that i had placed under images folder. Please suggest on this issue.

Comment: Hi Suman, if you see that the logo changes after doing these replacements to the jar, then as it means that your changes have been applied, there is one thing you will need to take into consideration here. That is the size of your logo. In the above documentation, please refer to the note that says "Note that the size of the images you use will affect the overall UI of your product." You will have to change the size of the logo to fit in. Shall we check this and see?